# space before itemize with enumitem

Tags: itemize, enumitem

I'm writing a report in which I describe numerous algorithms in the following way:

```
"[algorithm name]  
input: [input]  
output: [output]  
- step 1  
...  
- step n"
```

My problem is that I'm also using the `enumitem` package to reduce the spacing between items and it adds an unwanted space between the output line and the beginning of the `itemize`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}  
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}  

\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep} 

\begin{document}  

algorithm name  
\textsc{input:} input  
\textsc{output:} output  
\begin{itemize}  
\item step 1  
\item step 2  
\item step 3  
\end{itemize}  
\end{document}
```

I tried making the first two lines part of the `itemize` by putting `"input"` and `"output"` as `\item` labels, but the difference in length makes them "right-aligned" (relatively to each other) and outside the body box.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I know this does not direclty address the question, but do you know the `algotihmicx` or `algorithm2e` packages ? They are specifically designed for the description of algorithms

Comment: I've heard of these packages, however, the algorithms I describe are rather linear (no loops or anything similar) so I don't think using them would really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nosep`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

algorithm name\\
\textsc{input:} input\\
\textsc{output:} output
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item step 1
\item step 2
\item step 3
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]